# How do I pull my image right while keeping it centered once collapsed in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make it so inside of this row there are two equal columns; text on the left side with an image on the right. The problem is when I set my first col as text and my second column with the image, I get what I want except once everything collapses my image is stacked below my text. I want my image to be above my text once stacked. I've tried using pull right but then my image is no longer centered once everything is stacked. How can I get my image on the right and my text on the left and have my image centered and above my text once stacked?

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="center-col">
                    <h1 class="title">header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem perspiciatis voluptatum a, quo nobis, non commodi quia repellendus sequi nulla voluptatem dicta reprehenderit, placeat laborum ut beatae ullam suscipit veniam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to offset the columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        <h1 class="title">header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem perspiciatis voluptatum a, quo nobis, non commodi quia repellendus sequi nulla voluptatem dicta reprehenderit, placeat laborum ut beatae ullam suscipit veniam.</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

And [here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/citebaxura/1/) for you. And [a link where you can read more](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

Btw. I had to use the "sm" grid because my screen is small, but I think you get the idea :)  -- Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Gorm Casper good answer and use it at `md size` or even look at using `@media` to show not show different containers with a reverse set up have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt4qve2e/1/embedded/result/)**.
Resize the window to see how it flows.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .desktop{display: block; }
    .tablet{display: none; }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) { 
    .desktop{display: none; }
    .tablet{display: block; }
}
```